Read old APL *.sf files
I need to get data out of old (~1990) APL  *.sf files. The old APL software will not run on current Windows verions.
Tried to read the files after installing DyalogAPL with no success. Could not find a way to tie to file.

.sf is the usual file extension for APL*PLUS component files. If from around 1990, then they are probably from APL*PLUS/PC (released 1982) or APL*PLUS/II (released 1989).
You can contact support@apl2000.com for help with extracting the data, or email support@dyalog.com for help with conversion to Dyalog APL.

Disclosure: I work for Dyalog Ltd.
